# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView on my unity game

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, uiwebview, cocoapods, google-mobile-ads

when upload my game on app store and then i got error.(Error is given below)

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.**

i have just use google mobile ads latest plugin in unity.
Make an xcode build and then install cocoa-pods using terminal. After that i have just check for UIWebView using this command "grep -r -F "UIWebView" ." then i got 2 lines of paths of executable file.(2 lines given below)

**Binary file ./Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds matches
Binary file ./Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds matches**

now how can i remove this error from cocoa-pods.
my app rejected in multiple time for same error so let me know any perfect solution for this error.

Unity version : **Unity-2020.3.20f1**
Google mobile ads unity version : **6.1.0**
Google mobile ads pod version : **pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.8'**
Xcode version : **13.1**

Comment: I met this problem and solved it with https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/145#issuecomment-627218351. Thx for the command `grep -r -F "UIWebView" .`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for google mobile ads only.
you can add WebKit.framework at UnityFramework > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries. Then After Update pods from terminal and upload project and apple approved game.